# ShinyApp not rendering plots in R

Tags: r, shiny, rendering

I am having problems rendering any visualizations on Shiny. I tried many different plots, none of them worked. Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage("Comex", 
                selectInput("paises","Selecione o Destino da Exportação",PAISES$NO_PAIS, selected = PAISES$NO_PAIS[55]),
                plotlyOutput(outputId = "table"))

server <- function(input, output){
  output$table <- renderTable({
    p <- RPostgres::dbGetQuery(con, paste0("SELECT CO_ANO, NO_PAIS, SUM(VL_FOB) 
                                        FROM comex 
                                        INNER JOIN paises ON comex.CO_PAIS = paises.CO_PAIS 
                                        WHERE (SG_UF_MUN = 'AL') AND (NO_PAIS = '",input$paises,"')
                                        GROUP BY NO_PAIS, CO_ANO"))
    View(p)
  })}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The SQL command seems fine, as I successfully extracted data with this very code outside the shinyApp structure.

Comment: Can you include stdout/stderr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The return value from `View(.)` is `NULL`, so your `renderTable` will always be blank; just make it `p`.
2. If your ui contains `plotlyOutput` then replace `renderTable` with `plotly::renderPlotly`. The ui-component for `shiny::renderTable` is `shiny::tableOutput`.

   `renderTable` is intended for a tabular display of `data.frame`-like data, not a plot.

   Choose either:

   ```r
   ui <- fluidPage(
     ...,
     tableOutput("table")
     ...
   )
   server <- function(input, output, session) {
     output$table <- renderTable({
       # code that returns a data.frame
     })
   }
   ```

   or

   ```r
   ui <- fluidPage(
     ...,
     plotlyOutput("myplot")
     ...
   )
   server <- function(input, output, session) {
     output$myplot <- plotly::renderPlotly({
       # ...
       plot_lt(...)
     })
   }
   ```

Comment: Excellent, it rendered the table now. However i met another issue: for some reason the SQL 'SUM(VL_FOB)' returns 0 on the shiny rendered table, while the same code returns the proper number in R.

Comment: That suggests that `input$paises` (in shiny) is not what you're using on your console. But that really is a different question, one that will be informed by sample data. Questions that include `shiny` and SQL queries are difficult to fashion, since the best way to ensure reproducibility is to create a `data.frame`, insert into a (temporary) table, and then run a `shiny` app that queries that table. Good luck!